# Number Format in Javascript + conversion?

Tags: javascript, php, regex, string, numbers

Apologies for the common question, but as I tried to find a direct answer to my problem on the forum it don't seem I found it.

See, I have an text input (id = avt_ht) in Javascript where I put a number received in form of a string, like this :

`1 200,00`

I take this value, convert it into a float with something like this :

```
var ht_txt = $("#avt_ht").val();
ht_txt = ht_txt.replace(' ', '');
var ht_val = parseFloat(ht_txt);
```

Then, I use it to make some calculation, like

```
var ttc_val = ht_val + tva_val;
```

Now my point is I want to convert these numbers again in order to give them the same format at my beginning. I tried somethings like this :

```
var ttc_txt = ttc_val.toLocaleString();
```

But It is not appropriate. I don't really know if I can use NumberFormat in JS like in PHP (it seems not to be the same way of using it), if I have to use a regex, etc...

Does someone knows how to do it ?

Comment: You need also replace comma with a dot for parseFloat to work properly.

Comment: What jcubic is saying is that in `parseFloat('1200,00')` only the '1200' part of the number is used, so strings like '1200,12' will not keep their decimal part, it must be '1200.12'.

Comment: Thanks, guys ! I help to have the cents modificated as well. But do you know why, if I try to modificate it again, It does not execute my `ht_txt.replace(' ', '');` ? I wonder if it was something to do with the fact that, if I change a unit, it doesn't show ",00"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `toFixed()` method of float:

```
var ttc_txt = parseFloat(ttc_val).toFixed(2);
```

Returns something like `"123.00"`
You can use it as string. If you need a strict type string, just add `+""` to expression:

```
var ttc_txt = parseFloat(ttc_val).toFixed(2)+"";
```

Comment: Great ! I just had to change my `toLocaleString` by your `.toFixed(2)+"";` and now my numbers don't have calculations troubles anymore. I just need to formate a little here and that. Thanks, Dmitry !!